# mySql Insert Syntax - Not Inserting What's Expected

Tags: javascript, mysql, put

I have this INSERT query.  It does create a record in the table, but "client" value is 0, and "short" value is null.  However, all of the console logs show the correct data.  I'm assuming this is a simple syntax error in my use of the question marks. But I can't find that, or seem to get it to work using just variable names either.  Any help is appreciated.

```
app.put("/audit/create", function (req, res) {
  console.log("It is getting to the route");
  const client = req.body.client;
  const short = req.body.short;
  console.log(`client: ${client}`);
  console.log(`short: ${short}`);
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
      connection.query(
        `INSERT INTO audits (client, short)
        VALUES (?, ?)`,
        [
          {
            client: client,
          },
          {
            short: short,
          },
        ],
        function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          res.json(results);
          console.log(`Audit has been created`);
        }
      );
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

I've also tried using the variables names of ${client}, ${short} in place of the questions marks... and that still gives me the same result. However the console logs that render ${client} and ${short} do log the correct data I'm expecting to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing objects as the values to the query?  Try just:

```
connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO audits (client, short) VALUES (?, ?)',
    [ client, short ],
    function ...
```

Comment: Doh!  I knew it had to be something that easy.  I'm actually pulling the data out of an object, so I guess that confused me on the syntax.  Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: if this answer helped you consider accepting it (by clicking on the big check mark) and/or upvoting it